# Oracle Connection Error in PHP. Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Tags: php, web, oracle11g, database-connection

I am working on this project where i need to connect to the Oracle database. I am using the latest version of WAMP 2.2 and also activated all the extensions related the Oracle in PHP extensions. I have used following code for the connection to Oracle Database.

```
<?php 

$dbHost = "192.168.0.205";
$dbHostPort="1523";
$dbServiceName = "orcl";
$usr = "system";
$pswd = "admin";
$dbConnStr = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
        (HOST=".$dbHost.")(PORT=".$dbHostPort."))
        (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=".$dbServiceName.")))";

if(!$dbConn = oci_connect($usr,$pswd,'192.168.0.205:1158/em')){
$err = oci_error();
trigger_error('Could not establish a connection: ' . $err['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}
else
{
echo "COnnected";
}

$strSQL = "SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL";

$stmt = oci_parse($dbConn,$strSQL);
if ( ! oci_execute($stmt) ){
$err = oci_error($stmt);
trigger_error('Query failed: ' . $err['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
};

while(oci_fetch($stmt)){
$rslt = oci_result($stmt, 1); print "<h3>query returned: ".$rslt."</h3>";
}
?>
```

Kindly suggest the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check `phpinfo()` to make sure the extensions really ARE being loaded. you may have modified the wrong .ini file (e.g. command line version, which will not affect SAPI mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OCI8 PHP extension is not available in your PHP installation. See the [manual of the OCI8 PHP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php) for installtion instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Looking into that link.

Comment: i installed the OCI8 extension and also activated it but still i get this error.